# AmazonS3 TransferObserver not calling onStateChanged on listener on completion

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I am making an Android app that has to download some images from Amazon S3.
I am doing this with their Android SDK like so:

```
private class DownloadS3ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        TransferUtility transferUtility = AmazonS3ClientHelper.getTransferUtility(imageView.getContext());
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download(BUCKET, fileName, file);
        observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                if (TransferState.COMPLETED.equals(state)) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                }
                Log.d("onStateChanged", state.toString() + " " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);
                Log.d("percentage", String.valueOf(percentage));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                Log.d("onError", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });

        return null;

    }
```

The problem is that even though the download finishes the onStateChanged method on the listener doesn't get called.
Even with breakpoints there, it sometimes stops there once but not always so I can't rely on that code to show my images.

Any ideas or better ways to achieve this?